# ssl_prefer_server_ciphers unknown directive

Tags: centos, nginx, ssl

I just compiled nginx v1.2.3 from source on a CentOS 6.3 server and am trying to use the `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` directive, but I am getting an error `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ssl_prefer_serfver_cipers" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/application:5` I am not seeing anywhere that this directive depends on any specific versions of other libraries, or even specific versions of nginx. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo.

You have:

```
ssl_prefer_serfver_cipers
```

It should be:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers
```